# sieve data from data

Tags: angular

This is my html. I have called the display[] array in html using for loop to display data.
My goal is to show all the list initially on page load and i also want to filter data based on the given date inputs.

But, as of now, when i filter data based on dates.
Example: if i select date from december 1st, 2020 to december 7th, 2020.
the grid showing empty, eventhough there is record on december 7th.
similarly, if i select date from december 1st to december 15th, it is showing all records below 15th december but not including 15th date data.

i want to show records in between the 2 dates selected.
But as of now, it is showing the dates below the selected 2nd date.

```
<input type="date" (change)="changeFirstInput($event)"> - 
  <input type="date" (change)="changeSecondInput($event)">
  <table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>date</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let o of display">   <!-- change made here only -->
          <td>{{o.name}}</td>
          <td>{{o.ts | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

From service i retrieved data into an array: Info[].
info contains an array of objects.
I also took a new array called display[] which should change dynamically on filtering the date.

```
   pattern = /(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/;
  public date1: Date = new Date("2000-01-01");
  public date2: Date = new Date();

  display = [];

  changeFirstInput(e) {
    this.date1 = new Date(e.target.value.replace(this.pattern, '$3-$2-$1'));
  }

  changeSecondInput(e) {
    this.display = Object.assign([], this.Info);
    this.date2 = new Date(e.target.value.replace(this.pattern, '$3-$2-$1'));

    this.display = this.Info.filter(o =>
      new Date(o.ts.replace(this.pattern, '$3-$2-$1')) >= this.date1 &&
      new Date(o.ts.replace(this.pattern, '$3-$2-$1')) <= this.date2);
  }

}
```

The data in Info[].
I need to filter this data based on the given date inputs.

```
0: {
id: 1, 
name: "Testing", 
status: "Y", 
ts: "2018-12-07T08:02:00.000Z"}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the method `changeSecondInput` where `incentivetype_ts` is not correctly converted into a `Date` without time part. You use the same`regex` pattern as for the filter `Date`.

Instead of using the `regex`, you could simply use [`String.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) as follows:

```
this.display = this.TermsInfo.filter(o =>
  new Date(o.ts.substring(0, 10)) >= this.date1 &&
  new Date(o.ts.substring(0, 10)) <= this.date2);
```

Please take a look at below runnable code snippet that illustrates what's currently going on and how it can be improved.

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1, name: "New Car", status: "Y", ts: "2020-12-07T08:02:00.000Z"},
  {id: 2, name: "CPO", status: "Y", ts: "2020-12-07T08:03:00.000Z"},
  {id: 9, name: "Service", status: "Y", ts: "2020-12-15T03:37:00.000Z"},
  {id: 10, name: "Parts", status: "Y", ts: "2020-12-15T03:38:00.000Z"},
  {id: 17, name: "Facility", status: "Y", ts: "2020-12-15T06:09:00.000Z"},
  {id: 25, name: "CSI", status: "Y", ts: "2020-12-15T08:34:00.000Z"}
];

const pattern = /(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/;

const date = '07.12.2020';
const dateConverted = date.replace(pattern, '$3-$2-$1');
console.log(dateConverted);

// current result
let convertedTs = data.map(o => o.ts.replace(pattern, '$3-$2-$1'));
console.log(convertedTs);

// corrected result
convertedTs = data.map(o => o.ts.substring(0, 10));
console.log(convertedTs);
```

Comment: @Shaki: I have to leave soon, but I can take a look at this question later. I'd however also like to understand why you marked the answer here as unaccepted again.